# How to resolve route on app init in Angular 13?

Tags: angular

What is best approach to resolve route before components are loaded? I don't want to use guard for every route, and I must load component on '/' path so parent '/' path without component with children routes are not an option. If there is some other way to use one guard for all routes where I can have '/' path with component let me know.

I currently tried with APP_INIT provider in my app.module.ts:

```
{
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: startupFactory,
            deps: [StartupService],
            multi: true
  }
```

then added factory:

```
export function startupFactory(startupService: StartupService) {
    return (): Promise<any> => {
        return startupService.load();
    }
}
```

and startup service:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class StartupService {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  load(): Promise<boolean> {
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);
    console.log('current url : ' + router.url);
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => resolve(true)));
  }
}
```

When I open any url like '/DashboardPage?p=33' it logs:

current url : '/'

Comment: So what do you wanna do again?

Comment: Add guards - in a loop

Comment: I concur - no idea what you’re asking for - and why?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to code it

```
const routes:Route[]=[...] //your routes

for(let r of routes){
    if(r is something){
       r.canActivate=YourGuard
    }
}
```

and

```
@NgModule({imports:RouterModule.forRoot(routes)}
```

it was written of top of my head so expect

1. typos
2. minor mistakes you will have to yourself